# What are the benefits of solarization?

Tags: lawn, weed-control, grass, crabgrass

I am trying to cull crabgrass from my desert yard.  I live in central Arizona.  The crabgrass will grow in intense heat and seems very robust.  It tends to grow more rapidly in shaded areas of the yard during summer but will also grow to some extent in seemingly detrimental environment conditions.

I want to get rid of any remaining crab grass as the landscaping is desert style with only indigenous plants.

I prefer to not use any chemicals.  I've done very good over the last 20 years but this one is beating me down.  I just can't seem to win.

I recently heard of solarization. What is this?  I'm not a gardener so I'm always running into terminology that is new to me.  From what I understand this is a possible solution but have no experience.

- Can someone explain the benefits of solarization?
- Will solarization have any negative possibilities associated with it?

Comment: I don't have a lawn though.  Desert landscaped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solarization is a combination killer by smothering and intense heat. This may work to kill your crabgrass, but some of it may still survive even this harsh treatment. Crab grass may even grow through the plastic if you don't get thick enough plastic.

I can't think of any long term drawbacks from an organic point of view, but the soil underneath will be made relatively barren and it may take time for the soil to repopulate with beneficial organisms.